# How To Move 3D Object By touch Dragging The Finger On the screen

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, touch

I want to move object by touch Dragging Finger By the Screen means object should follow direction of finger I have found a game on Play Store in that game ball is moving left and right by touching that exactly what want to make in my game
Link of my game:- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ketchapp.hop

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to set the position of the players finger on the screen to a worldpoint and set that world point to a Vector3. the move the ball to the worldpoint Vector3 (asuming you want to use a speed to move with, else just use .position).

```
//Variables
public transform ball;
public float speed = 10f;
//i do not know about touch screen controls. this is something i will link to below!

//Get Touch Position
 Vector3 worldTouchPos = screenTouchPos; //worldTouchPos = the touch position in world space, and the screenTouchPos is the touch position on the screen ( so a value between 0 and 1 in both x and y).

//Ball Movement

ball.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(ball.position //pos to move from\\ ,worldTouchPos //pos to move to\\, speed);
```

Touch Controls Link to YT video: [Brackeys video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bp2PiFC9sSs) , [/ The Other video that you want to watch!!!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VmGmMRhR-Ts)